# What does [[ $(echo ${lines} | grep \'_SUCCESS\') ]] mean?

Tags: bash

I came across this bash command and not able to interpret as it always print NO which is in else part.

```sh
if [[ $(echo ${lines} | grep \'_SUCCESS\') ]] ; then echo \'Y\'; else echo \'N\'; fi;
exit 0
```

I have _SUCCESS file ins

Comment: What is the value of `$lines` at this point? Otherwise, it's probably badly written bash code... intention was to check whether `lines` contains the string `_SUCCESS`.

Comment: You can omit `[[` expression. Instead use `if echo $lines | grep -q \'_SUCCESS\' ; then echo \'Y\'; else echo \'N\'; fi`

Comment: That means, whoever wrote it will surely run grep on each line... which is not what grep was written to do, because grep can parse an enter file(s) by it self...

Comment: `type [` and `type [[` both shows that they are not.

Comment: @Jetchisel `[[` is only a builtin; `[` is both a builtin and /usr/bin/[` for optimisation purposes (just like `echo` is both a builtin, and `/usr/bin/echo`)

Comment: Optimisation purposes?

Comment: @Jetchisel Speed is cheap now, but think of the time when shells were created. `[` is found in many shell scripts, and executing it from disk every time is very slow. So shells started incorporating some of the more common commands as builtins, to avoid frequent disk access. I assume the program `/usr/bin/[` is still there for backward compatibility; `[[` was created afterwards, and did not need backwards compatibility, so there is no equivalent program, only the builtin.

Answer (score 2):

`[[ ... ]]` is a `bash` construct that will transform the truth value of the expression within into a exit status code 0/1. `if` will execute the `then` branch if the exit status code is 0, and the `else` branch otherwise.

Within `[[ ... ]]`, you still get command substitution, so `echo ${lines} | grep \'_SUCCESS\'` will be executed, and its output substituted into the command. These commands will output the line inside `${lines}` that contains `'_SUCCESS'` (with single quotes!) if such is present, or nothing.

`[[ ... ]]` that contains a single string evaluates as true if string is non-empty, and false if empty.

Thus, the `then` branch will execute if `${files}` contains `'_SUCCESS'`. If you are always getting a `'N'` as output, it follows `${files}` does not contain `'_SUCCESS'` (even if it maybe does contain `_SUCCESS`). If you want to look for `_SUCCESS` (without quotes), then `grep _SUCCESS` or equivalently `grep '_SUCCESS'` suffices.

This is a long way around of writing what sergio says in comments: `grep` will not only output (or not output) the lines, it will also signal with its exit status code whether something is found or not, and can thus directly be used as the `if` condition, without using `[[ ... ]]`.